# Calling Python file from c++ using CreateProcess

Tags: python, c++, c, mfc

I would like to run python script file on MFC Button click using CreateProcess(), so that I can capture the output of a process in realtime using a pipes.

```
CString sCmd = "Cmd.Exe";
CString sParms = " /c python.exe C:\\WinApp\\Debug\\printx.py";
BOOL fRet = ExecAndProcessOutput(sCmd, sParms);


BOOL ExecAndProcessOutput(LPCSTR szCmd, LPCSTR szParms)
{
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES rSA = { 0 };
    rSA.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    rSA.bInheritHandle = TRUE;

    HANDLE hReadPipe, hWritePipe;
    CreatePipe(&hReadPipe, &hWritePipe, &rSA, 25000);

    PROCESS_INFORMATION rPI = { 0 };
    STARTUPINFO         rSI = { 0 };
    rSI.cb = sizeof(rSI);
    rSI.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW | STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    rSI.wShowWindow = SW_SHOWNORMAL;// SW_HIDE;  // or SW_SHOWNORMAL or SW_MINIMIZE
    rSI.hStdOutput = hWritePipe;
    rSI.hStdError = hWritePipe;

    CString sCmd; 
    sCmd.Format("\"%s\" %s", (LPCSTR)szCmd, (LPCSTR)szParms);

    BOOL fRet = CreateProcess(NULL, (LPSTR)(LPCSTR)sCmd, NULL,NULL, TRUE, 0, 0, 0, &rSI, &rPI);
    if (!fRet) 
    {
        return(FALSE);
    }
}
```

In summary, passing parameter to the 2nd argument for the Createprocess is:

```
"Cmd.Exe"  /c python.exe C:\WinApp\Debug\printx.py
```

some reason when I run this code createprocess I don't get any error as a return argument. But python file named - printx.py not running.

Appreciates any help on this.

### Thanks,

Comment: why not run `python.exe` directly rather than through `cmd.exe`?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Tried as follows:                                          
        CString sCmd = "python.Exe";
 CString sParms = " /c printx.py";                                                                             didn't work.